# Trouble with DX11 Engine

Tags: c++, directx-11

I am following a tutorial for building a DX11Engine on youtube and I have become stuck. I am trying to render a sprite to the screen but when I try to run it I am getting

> Access violation reading location 0x00000000".

The problem is occurring at the line:

```
result = device->CreateVertexShader(vertexShaderBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), vertexShaderBuffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &m_vertexShader);
```

Which is in Shader.cpp.

I have uploaded my code on to Git Hub https://github.com/nowayout2k/PJTS-CPP-DX11Engine  . Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You should take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and it's [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access violation at 0x00000000 sounds like you accessed a null pointer. It is possible that you attempted to call a virtual method on it, thus the process attempted to read the virtual table pointer at the beginning of the object and failed, because it would be the zero address.

Make sure that the variables `device` and `vertexShaderBuffer` aren't null pointers. If they are, it could indicate that an error occured at the time of their initialization.

Comment: It appears that device is NULL but I do not know why. I will continue looking.

Comment: Found it I was returning zero instead of device fp. Thanks for your help.